# Flash var Loader issue - animation changing

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I've use a loader action script for a few banners I've been working on, and usually things go relatively smoothly (for Flash). However, the animation changes once I guide the image to the code. Has this happened to any one else? Below is the code I am using:

var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://972b6ac7e316515e1890-2848ccf658e0edc35f614dd3380d9fcb.r27.cf2.rackcdn.com/Background_othersizes.png");
imageLoader.load(image);
addChild (imageLoader);

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having? What do you mean by "guide the image to the code"?

Comment: The specific issue I'm having is that once the code is implemented, the image animation changes from what I had originally animated. Guide simply is reference to the command that is required to "attach" the code to the image (right click layer with the image, and select guide)

Comment: I think we would probably need to see more of your project and how the above snippet fits with in the grander scope to fully understand the issue.

Comment: Alright, how do we go about that?

Comment: Post more of the code, post screenshots of how you have your FLA timeline set up, etc.

Comment: Here is what it's supposed to do: http://social.och09.com/BrightHorizons/K-Prep/BRIG-072_300x250_v1.html

Here's what it's doing when I implement the code:
http://social.och09.com/BrightHorizons/K-Prep/BRIG-072_300x250_v2.html

And here is a screen shot of the code I am working with:
http://social.och09.com/BrightHorizons/K-Prep/ScreenShot_v2.png

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have created animation in the Flash IDE with static image (linked from the library), and now you try to add image in runtime. Loading of the image is asynchronous process, so I would recommend account it in your animation and logic.

Also place in your `MovieClip` where image will be loaded, transparent shape as a background, of the same size as image, so environment will be aware of display object size, and all your transformations over `MovieClip` will be accounted accordingly. Also check placement and scaling of the image.